# What is the difference between dhclient.leases and dhclient."interface-name".leases?

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, dhcp

I'm trying to setup DHCP on a server, and get the IPs from another client machine.

Before requesting a new IP from the DHCP server on a client, I listed all the files I had in the var/lib/dhcp folder, and got a file called dhclient.leases and dhclient.enp0s3.leases. What is the difference between these two? They both contain the same text, so what is the purpose of having the content of dhclient.enp0s3.leases in both files? When I requested a new IP, I got a new entry in dhclient.leases, but it didn't create the dhclient.enp0s9.leases file I expected it to create. I can ping my client with fixed-address 192.168.100.201 from server, so I guess it works. But is it an error, or might something fail later, because I didn't get the dhclient.enp0s9.leases file?

```
lease {                                                                                                                                                       
  interface "enp0s9";                                                                                                                                         
  fixed-address 192.168.100.201;                                                                                                                              
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;                                                                                                                           
  option dhcp-lease-time 3600;                                                                                                                                
  option dhcp-message-type 5;                                                                                                                                 
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.100.1;                                                                                                                   
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.100.1;                                                                                                                
  option domain-search "dave3610.com.";                                                                                                                       
  option domain-name "dave3610.com";                                                                                                                          
  renew 0 2018/03/18 14:44:50;                                                                                                                                
  rebind 0 2018/03/18 15:09:31;                                                                                                                               
  expire 0 2018/03/18 15:17:01;                                                                                                                               
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: did you check the file permissions of dhclient.leases? if the dhclient cannot write to dhclient.leases, it basically creates a new lease file. It could also result in having 2 IPs for the same network interface.